# How to find all solutions for $-\cos(2\pi \sqrt x)+2 = \cos(2\pi(x-2)/7) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone please help me solve this trigonometric equation. I need to find all positive solutions (I think they are infinite so I just need the formula to generate them).

$$-\cos(2\pi \sqrt x)+2 = \cos(2\pi(x-2)/7) $$

Greatly appreciated

First of all, thanks for all the comments. To further clarify the question here is a similar but simpler one I can do:
$$-\cos(2\pi x /6)+2 = \cos(2\pi(x-2)/7) $$
The solution to this would be $30 + 42n$ where $30$ is the first positive solution and $42$ is lowest common multiple.
So what I am looking for is something similar but for the above equation instead.

Comment: Please show what have you tried and where you failed

Comment: Hint: the smallest values  on the left side of the equation equal $ \ 1 \ $ , while the _largest_ values on the right side equal $ \ 1 \ $ .  Where do the minima for the left side occur?  Where do the _maxima_ on the right side occur?  (Do "the twain ever meet"?)

Comment: Very crude trick problem, the point of which is that if max value of $f(x)$ is  $1$, and $f(x_1) + f(x_2) = 2$, then one can conclude that $f(x_1) = 1$ and $f(x_2) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$-\cos(2\pi x^{0.5})$ is between $-1$ and $+1.$ So when you add $2$ to it, that must be between $+1$ and $+3$ (inclusive).

On the right side of the equation, $\cos(2\pi(x-2)/7)$ must remain between $-1$ and $+1,$ inclusive. The only way these two can be equal is therefore when both are equal to $+1.$

A cosine is equal to $+1$ only when it is the cosine of an integer multiple of $2\pi.$ So $x^{0.5}$ and $(x-2)/7$ must both be integers.

Comment: True, so any solution must be the square of an integer and be divisible by 7 when two is taken away. But I need a math formula for this like we usually have with trig like +-2 +2pi n if such solution exists?

Comment: @Fred : So the question is: Which perfect squares are $2$ more than a multiple of $7$? One of those can be found quickly. $\qquad$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} 0^2 & = 0 \equiv 0 \bmod 7 \\ 1^2 & = 1 \equiv 1\bmod 7 \\ 2^2 & = 4 \equiv 4\bmod 7 \\ 3^2 & = 9 \equiv 2 \bmod 7 \\ 4^2 & = 16 \equiv 2\bmod 7 \\ 5^2 & = 25 \equiv4\bmod 7 \\ 6^2& =36\equiv1\bmod7 \end{align} $$

Comment: Ah thats a nice way to put it, so how would I find the solution to that in a systematic way?

Comment: @Fred : A crucial fact is that if $a\equiv c\bmod7$ and $b\equiv d\bmod 7$ then $ac\equiv bd\bmod 7.$ With that plus the above, you can show that the solutions are the SQUARES OF numbers congruent to $3$ or $4\bmod7. \qquad$

Comment: Ah mods I was trying to avoid those ;) because i would have to try all the values and select thoes which return 2 which could take a while for very big numbers do you think this can be solved with trig instead of mods?

Comment: In R I entered the following commands and got the following output:
$$
\begin{align}
& > \texttt{1000^2 %% 7} \\
& \texttt{[1] 1} \\
& > \texttt{1001^2 %% 7} \\
& \texttt{[1] 0} \\
& > \texttt{1002^2 %% 7} \\
& \texttt{[1] 1} \\
& > \texttt{1003^2 %% 7} \\
& \texttt{[1] 4} \\
& > \texttt{1004^2 %% 7} \\
& \texttt{[1] 2}
\end{align}
$$
So $x= 1004^2$ is a solution. $\qquad$